# process EventHandler from getOnKeyPressed

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, keypress

I have element in `fxml` and i set method at `onKeyPressed` there

```
<TableView fx:id="topTable" onKeyPressed="#copyToClipboard" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
```

but i don't understand how to get KeyCode's from this EventHandler in method.

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<ObservableList<String>> topTable;
    ...
    public void copyToClipboard(){
    System.out.println(topTable.getOnKeyPressed().toString());
}
```

With help of this action i would like to copy data from cells of `TableColumn`.
Can someone explain me what can i do with Handler from `getOnKeyPressed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an event handler via FXML the method in the controller can either take no parameters or one parameter with the appropriate event type. In your case, since you're using `onKeyPressed`, you can define the controller method like so:

```
public void copyToClipboard(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.isShortcutDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.C) {
        Clipboard cp = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        // add your data to the clipboard
    }    
}
```

For more information:

- Javadoc of [`Clipboard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html)
- Documentation of [controller event handler methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers)

---

To know which `Event` type the parameter should be, look at the event handler property you're attempting to use. In your question you are setting the [`onKeyPressed` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyPressedProperty) via FXML. This property has the following signature:

```
ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super KeyEvent>>
```

The type of `Event` the `EventHandler` is supposed to handle is stated in the generic type of the `EventHandler`; in this case, `KeyEvent`.

There are many of these "event handler properties" declared for `Node`. Some subclasses will add their own—such as the `onAction` property of `ButtonBase` (uses an `ActionEvent`).

If it helps, you can think of setting event handler properties from FXML as similar to using method references<sup>*</sup>:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private TableView<?> topTable;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        topTable.setOnKeyPressed(this::copyToClipboard);
    }

    public void copyToClipboard(KeyEvent event) {}

}
```

<sup>* This is not actually the case as what the `FXMLLoader` does is more complicated (reflection).</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation! It works! But anyway i didn't understand when i can get a parameter and when i can't. And how to know the `Class` of this parameter (in your example it is `KeyEvent`. How did you got it?)?

Comment: @Дмитрий Updated answer. Also, `isShortcutDown` queries if the platform-specific shortcut key is down. Basically, my example code is saying: "copy to clipboard when `Ctrl+C` is pressed" (or the Mac equivalent). See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isShortcutDown()).